# Tunnel TCP over Tor2Web

Tags: proxy, tunnel

Did anybody manage to do this?
I've tried every tunneling software I could find that tunnels over http. No luck, various errors, even with different tor2web hosts.
I was looking into using the tor2web proxy as a way to port forward to my different boxes.

Answer (score 2):

tor2web is an HTTP proxy, it takes in requests for "foo.tld" and makes a corresponding request to "foo.onion" over Tor and provides back the response. It's important to note that it makes a corresponding request, it doesn't just take in an arbitrary TCP stream and forward it on for you, it's looking for a well formed HTTP request to make on your behalf.

As such the only way to transfer some arbitrary data stream over HTTP is to implement some transport method *on top of* HTTP which both you and the remote party understand to encapsulate stream data inside of some series of HTTP requests and responses between you and the service behind tor2web.

Comment: Yes, when I use a tool like crowbar or httptunnel or chisel (websockets, ok maybe not supported) it still does not work. Is there a known way?

Comment: Websockets are not HTTP, there's probably not a known way. I'm not sure about the other suggestions. You want a bespoke solution, you're going to have to create a bespoke solution.

Comment: Working on it. I've succesfully created 2 python scripts, a http server and a client who only communicate through URL-content and GET-responses

Comment: Will post the result here